# How to cycle through tasks and keep track of it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm developing a web application in PHP in which a user can create tasks for other users to compete.

Those tasks are then stored in MySQL Database.

My question is, How can I cycle through those tasks from the database and present It to the users while keeping track of which tasks that user has completed to avoid presenting the same task to that user. All while also providing the user who created a task with number of users who have completed his/her task.

How can I accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: please provide your code. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  I can paraphrase:  I am building a multi-user task system (with Php and Mysql) what do I do?

Comment: @elegisandi I'm asking for theoretical advice on how to go about doing this as I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as i can see, i think many - to - many relational tables is what you are looking for, assuming a user can do many tasks and any task can be done by multiple users. You would need 3 tables:

- Tasks: `task_id`, `task_name`, `whatever_else_you_need_like_details`
- Users: `user_id`, `w/e`
- Relations: `task_id`, `user_id`, `status` <-    the last one is for
  checking weather a specific task is done by a    specific user or in
  general to see all tasks assigned to a user with    their status and
  vica versa.

Read up on `mano-to-many relations`, `foreign keys` and `left/right joins`:)